# Problems loading csv files into mysql with spanish accents / Kaggle BIMBO Competition?

Tags: mysql, kaggle

I am trying to import data into mysql from a csv but having no luck. The data looks as follows:

```
 Agencia_ID,Town,State 
 1110,2008 AG. LAGO FILT,"MÉXICO, D.F."
 1111,2002 AG. AZCAPOTZALCO,"MÉXICO, D.F."
 1112,2004 AG. CUAUTITLAN,ESTADO DE MÉXICO
 1113,2008 AG. LAGO FILT,"MÉXICO, D.F."
 1114,2029 AG.IZTAPALAPA 2,"MÉXICO, D.F."
 1116,2011 AG. SAN ANTONIO,"MÉXICO, D.F."
 1117,2001 AG. ATIZAPAN,ESTADO DE MÉXICO
```

I've tried uploading the data using the following command on mysql

```
load data local infile 
'/home/wrodezno/Documents/Kaggle/Bimbo/Data/town_state.csv' 
into table town_state 
character set latin1
fields terminated by ','
optionally enclosed by '"'
lines terminated by '\n'
(Agencia_ID,Town,State);
```

However, the results are not what I would expect.
It seems to be reading all the data into two rows.
The header row and then everything else.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are working on Kaggle's Grupo Bimbo competition.  Could you show more output on your errors?